# count number of files on basis of filename in hdfs directory

Tags: bash, shell, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have a HDFS directory with more than thousand records and which contains different filenames. I have to count files on basis of file name.
Since i have thousand of files,i cannot give specific filename for count.

For example directory contains below files

/a/b/a.txt

/a/b/b.txt

/a/b/c.txt

/a/b/a.txt

/a/b/b.txt

/a/b/c.txt

Result should be

a.txt  2

b.txt  2

c.txt  2

Comment: I don't think same filenames are possible in a folder.

Comment: Did you mean to say `a/a/a.txt`, `a/b/a.txt`, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means an efficient solution, but if you just want to script something up quickly, it'll do:

```
find . -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort
```

Explanation:

- **find** all files in the current directory, and print their **basename** (just the filename, remove the parent directories). To change the root of the search, specify a path rather than `.`
- **sort** the list alphabetically (this is required for the next step to work)
- **count** each item (-c flag of `uniq` counts each occurence)
- sort that list to view in ascending order.

On my system, this gives something that looks like

```
  ... removed some output for clarity ...
  2 CMakeLists.txt
  2 heads
  2 hello
  2 info
  2 origin
  2 refs
  2 remotes
  2 test
  2 test.cpp
  4 .gitignore
  4 HEAD
  4 master
  5 Makefile
```

Comment: i was doing something wrong...corrected that...thanks for help.